# Can't find file after using adb pull. What is happening

Tags: adb

I'm trying to pull an APK from my phone, and I'm using `adb` as all seasoned Android nerds do, obviously. And I type in

`c:\Windows>adb pull /data/app/~~dBj1dZPAMtNiEq660lbkhQ==/com.devsisters.gb-0ME7a_ZJlhcbVcXs1kxGyQ==/split_googleplay_assetpack.apk C:\`

So, it should obviously be pulled to the `C:\` directory, right? and it tells me it succeeded!

`3421 KB/s (945352468 bytes in 269.850s)`

So, everything should be there. But I go to check `C:\` and guess what.
It's not there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have executed exactly the posted command? Because if I execute the same command in Windows cmd (just for a different installed apk) then I get the error message `'C:\': No such file or directory` (Windows 10, adb 1.0.41 / 34.0.5-10900879).